# How to make a OkHttp call within a Android.WorkManager?

Tags: okhttp, android-workmanager

I have several OkHttp requests that I need to send and even if there is no internet for some time, in the end they have to be delivered. It seems that WorkManager is a good API that can handle this. 
But how to integrate OkHttp requests and WorkManager?
And  (second) be able to get notifications?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used same as you want:

You can do that like:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    // DO OKHTTP REQUEST HERE........

    return Result.success();
}
```

Note : Do not use any UI thread here like progress bar.